# Check to see if a string is equal to a valid month ruby?

Tags: ruby, datetime

Is there a way to see if a string is a valid month name in ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
require 'date'
Date::MONTHNAMES.include? string
```

Note that this will return `true` if string is `nil`. All month names are capitalized, so if you don't care for case:

```
Date::MONTHNAMES.include?(string && string.capitalize)
```

If you want nil to return false:

```
!!string && Date::MONTHNAMES.include?(string.capitalize)
```

Comment: You have to `require 'date'` for the constant `MONTHNAMES` to be defined.

Answer (score 1):

I will use the method `#grep`. It will validate all the possible month strings.

```
require 'date'
Date::MONTHNAMES.grep(Regexp.new(string, true)).empty?
```

If the above method returns `true`, that means the string is not *valid* month name, otherwise  it is.

I passed the second *argument* to the method `Regexp::new` as `true`, to make the *regex* pattern *case insensitive*.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `Date.parse` method instead. This has benefits over using the `Date::MONTHNAMES.include? string` as it will take into account for short handed month strings (eg: jun, aug, dec etc).

```
require 'date'
if (Date.parse(string) rescue false)
 # code for valid month string
else
# code for invalid month string
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regex

```
months_regex = /(Jan|Febr)uary|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|(Octo|Novem|Decem)ber/


string =~ regex
```

the position, 0 , will return if there is a match else it will return nill